# Nothing gets typed in EditText

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-edittext

If focus changes from first EditText i.e mTxtFirstName and focus goes to mTxtEmail then validate if mTxtFirstName is empty.So following steps i do:-

> 1. The new focussed mTxtEmail will lose focus i.e mTxtEmail.ClearFocus()
> 2. mTxtFirstName will get focus again i.e  mTxtFirstName.RequestFocus()
> 3. mTxtFirstName shows error i.e mTxtFirstName.SetError("Non Empty Field",null)
> 4. Cursor set to 0th position i.e. TxtFirstName.SetSelection(0)
> 5. get the keyboard input i.e ShowKeyboard(mTxtFirstName)

All things happens but when i starts typing in mTxtFirstName the typing happens in previous focussed EditText Field.I have also tried using Emulator keyboard option but no success.See Screenshot for more Info.How to make typing enable in mTxtFirstName only till it is non empty.Please Help.

Output Screen:

[image]

**Here is the .axml file**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#DEDEDC"
    android:minWidth="300dp"
    android:minHeight="400dp"
    android:id="@+id/MyDialog_Layout">
    <EditText
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:hint="First Name"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtFirstName" />
    <EditText
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"
        android_layout_below="@+id/txtFirstName"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/txtEmailId"
        android:layout_height="40dp" />
    <EditText
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtEmailId"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtPassword" />
    <EditText
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtPassword"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:hint="Confirm Password"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtConfirmPassword" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtPassword"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp">
        <Button
            android:text="Sign Up"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtConfirmPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnDialogEmail"
            android:layout_weight="15"
            android:background="@drawable/ButtonSignUpStyle"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:height="70dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Here is Code from .cs file**

```
 public override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();


    mTxtFirstName.FocusChange += (object sender, View.FocusChangeEventArgs e) =>

                {
                    if (!e.HasFocus)
                    {
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(mTxtFirstName.Text.Trim()))

                        {

                                {
                                    mTxtEmail.ClearFocus();
                                    mTxtFirstName.RequestFocus();
                                    mTxtFirstName.Focusable = true;
                                    mTxtFirstName.SetError("Non Empty Field", null);
                                    mTxtFirstName.SetSelection(0);
                                    ShowKeyboard(mTxtFirstName);
                                }
                        }
                    }

                };


            }


            public static void ShowKeyboard(View pView)
            {
                    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService) as InputMethodManager;
                    inputMethodManager.ShowSoftInput(pView, ShowFlags.Forced);
                    inputMethodManager.ToggleSoftInput(ShowFlags.Forced, HideSoftInputFlags.ImplicitOnly);
            }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not set focus back to the same sender within the `FocusChange` listener (event) without causing issues in the UI (like double focus indictors and the inability to touch (set focus) and perform edits with the widget.

But when focus has been received to another widget, you can `ClearFocus` the current widget and `RequestFocus` to your widget with the input error:

```
protected override void OnResume()
{
    base.OnResume();

    EditText txtFirstName = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtFirstName);
    EditText txtEmailId = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtEmailId);
    EditText textPassword = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtPassword);
    EditText txtConfirmPassword = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtConfirmPassword);

    EventHandler<View.FocusChangeEventArgs> reFocusOnError = (object sender, View.FocusChangeEventArgs e) =>
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFirstName.Text.Trim()))
        {
            var editTextSender = sender as EditText;
            if (editTextSender.Id != Resource.Id.txtFirstName)
            {
                editTextSender.ClearFocus();
                txtFirstName.SetError("Non Empty Field", null);
                txtFirstName.Focusable = true;
                txtFirstName.ShowSoftInputOnFocus = true;
                txtFirstName.RequestFocus();
                InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
                inputManager.ShowSoftInput(txtFirstName, ShowFlags.Implicit);
            }

        }
    };

    txtFirstName.FocusChange += reFocusOnError;
    txtEmailId.FocusChange += reFocusOnError;
    textPassword.FocusChange += reFocusOnError;
    txtConfirmPassword.FocusChange += reFocusOnError;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @SushiHangover, code works exactly the way i wanted

Answer (score 0):

change your xml code to

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:hint="First Name"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtFirstName"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
```

and change in java code on button click listener

```
 if ( mTxtFirstName.length() == 0 ||  mTxtFirstName.isEmpty() ) {
                     mTxtFirstName.setError("First Name Required");
}
```

also add in manifest where your activity is specified

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

Remove

```
  mTxtEmail.ClearFocus();
                                    mTxtFirstName.RequestFocus();
                                    mTxtFirstName.Focusable = true;
                                    mTxtFirstName.SetError("Non Empty Field", null);
                                    mTxtFirstName.SetSelection(0);
                                    ShowKeyboard(mTxtFirstName);
```

Try this

Comment: thanks for the reply but i want to validate the FirstName field on focus change.I want the user to know one's mistake immediately as the focus changes.I don't want the user to fill all the fields of FirstName,Email,Password,ConfirmPassword and then on button Click User gets to know ,what he/she has done wrong.

Comment: it's pretty simple try this

EditText txtEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittxt);

 txtEdit.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {
               // code to execute when EditText loses focus
            }
        }
    });

http://stackoverflow.com/a/8657882/4342876

Comment: Same i am doing with txtEdit.FocusChange correctly.The problem lies with the code:-             mTxtEmail.ClearFocus();
                                    mTxtFirstName.RequestFocus();
                                    mTxtFirstName.Focusable = true;
                                    mTxtFirstName.SetError("NonEmptyField",null);
                                    mTxtFirstName.SetSelection(0);
                                    ShowKeyboard(mTxtFirstName);
                                }

Something i am missing here because of that typing happens in mTxtEmail rather than mTxtFirstName